# What do Solaris pmap entries dev: and ino: represent?

Tags: command-line, memory, solaris

Running the pmap command on a process in Solaris, I see certain processes have blocks of memory with tags like the following:

> dev:337,2 ino=2433431

What do the dev and ino represent? My assumption is device and inode, but that is just a guess.  Is there a way to reverse-debug what this memory is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are probably /var/run mmaped files. I just checked and found for example /var/run/tzsync being mmaped by many processes. That particular file allows timezone patches not to require a reboot to be effective.

Comment: How did you determine which file was being mmaped?  Is there a way to do a reverse look-up with the device number and inode number?  I tried 'find / -inum <ino>', but didn't have any luck.

Comment: The tzsync file was reported by `pmap`, `pfiles` and `find -inum`. The latter should find it at least under /proc/<pid>/fd.